# WooCommerce actions - hook names

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been searching for ages and cannot find a real answer to this

I am looking for all of the actions that can be used in the wp function `add_action` for woocommerce

I have checked the woocommerce docs but it doesn't seem to list the names of the hooks

Comment: Ok, as an example I am using the hook 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' - where is this in those docs?

Comment: woocommerce_order_status_{$new_status} action abstract-wc-order.php

Comment: I'm sorry - what have you commented that for?

Comment: That's the hook you said you're using. Replace {$new_status} with whatever order statuses exist?

Comment: I want other hook examples too - not just the order status. Hooks like when a product is added or removed to an already created order

Comment: `woocommerce_new_order_item`, `woocommerce_update_order_item`, `woocommerce_before_delete_order_item`, `woocommerce_delete_order_item` are the hooks for product added, updated and removed to order. Everything is in those docs.

Comment: these are working fine - but i cannot get `woocommerce_update_order_item` to work - is it definitely correct?